# Get current user id in startup (asp.net core 5)

Tags: asp.net-core

How I can get current user id in **Configure Services** method.
I need to send user Id when inject some service.
or it is not possible ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current user in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641338/how-to-get-current-user-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: hi @AlokRaj . No I need to get user id in startup , not in controller

Comment: Did you know that startup runs only ones.  Doesn' t matter how many users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to send user Id when inject some service. or it is not possible ?

`HttpContext` is only valid during a request. The `ConfigureServices` method in Startup is not a web call and, as such, does not have a `HttpContext`. So the User information also cannot be got. You need register the `IHttpContextAccessor` and DI it by constructor in your services. Then you could get `HttpContext.User` infomation successfully.

Register the IHttpContextAccessor:

```
services.AddScoped<IHttpContextAccessor,HttpContextAccessor>();
```

DI in the service:

```
public interface IService
{
    string GetUserId();
}

public class Service : IService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public Service(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public string GetUserId()
    {
        var id = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        return id;
    }
}
```

Register the service:

```
services.AddScoped<IHttpContextAccessor,HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddScoped<IService, Service>(); //add this...
```

More explanations you could refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63028597/11398810).